# How to exclude a tag in html using SimpleHTMLDOMParser

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing, domparser

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

I am using this to parse an html file in php

Example

```
$html = str_get_html("<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>"); 
$e = $html->find("div", 0);

echo $e->innertext; // Returns: " foo <b>bar</b>"
echo $e->plaintext; // Returns: " foo bar"
```

I want to extract only foo (in other words, I want to exclude the bold tag). How can I do that ?